# Can i define methods in exception classes other than __init__ in Python?

Tags: python, class, methods, custom-exceptions

As the question already asks, I'm aware of building a custom exception class like this:

```
class MyException(Exception) :

   def __init__(self, message='My error message') :
       self.message = message
       super(MyException, self).__init__(message)
```

which will build a custom Exception class object with a predefined overwritable message.

I wanted to know if it's possible to define more methods in it, other than `__init__`, and what would the effects of that be.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can. It won't have any effect other than having those other methods on it.